# To Apply for a visa: need "one-year health insurance" - but can only book insurance for 365 days

Tags: france, insurance, working-holiday

I wish to apply for a working holiday visa for France. One of the requirements in order to get the visa is:

"Compulsory one-year health insurance (covering
all risks of sickness, maternity, disability and
repatriation) regardless of the travel plans or
intended length of stay decided by the
applicant."

I asked the consulate what one year exactly constitutes, and their reply was that the insurance must last from the date of your flight, until the same date the next year (ie 3rd of April 2015 to 3rd of April 2016). When including the fact next year is a leap year, that means you need 367 days of insurance.

However, none of the travel insurance I've been looking at will go over 365 days. What can I do? Thanks.

Comment: +1, it is even worse for French going to Canada on the same visa, they are now allowed two years, and likely need an insurance covering the whole trip.

Answer (score 7):

First, it would help if you told us where you permanently reside. Indeed, if you are from the Quebec province, there is an agreement between the RAMQ (medical insurance in Quebec) and the French Sécurité Sociale.

If you are from somewhere else, you might still find some insurances covering for more than a year. I found [Bon Voyage](https://buy.travelinsurance.ca/Content.aspx?k=aboutInsurance), [Desjardins](http://www.desjardins.com/particuliers/assurances/assurance-voyage/index.jsp) (but they say you should call them for such a long duration). These are for Canada ([found here](http://pvtistes.net/france/dossiers/les-demarches-administratives-pour-la-demande-du-pvt-france/6/)), there are probably some for your permanent residence country.

In general, I let you check [this page from PVTistes.net](http://pvtistes.net/france/le-pvt/), which contains information about the WHV for France (in French, but I guess you can read French). They have explained the different procedures depending on where you reside. And [this forum](http://pvtistes.net/forum/obtenir-son-pvt-france/23990-pvt-france-quelle-assurance-choisir.html) covers specifically insurances (apparently the people there are mostly Canadians, though).